# Error on inserting JSON in Go Gorm

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I am working in Go using Gorm as "ORM", I have a postgres database and I am trying to perform an update operation over one of the tables,  the thing is that I have defined a JSON column and that column is giving me troubles to make the update.

To generate that JSON I am using [go simple json](http://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson), I printed the object before make the insert and I have this:

{ID:1 ResourceName:someresource ResourceKey:level1@mail.com  MyJson:{"Creator":"some creator","GACode":"UA-sample","URL":"www.url.com"}}

Then I have problems to update in the db due that is says that the json is not valid. I printed the sql sentence, and I have:

```
UPDATE "Table" SET "ResourceName" = 'someresource', "ResourceKey" = 'level1@mail.com', , "AccountStatus" = 'Active', "MyJson" = '{&#34;Creator&#34;&#34;some creator&#34;&#34;GACode&#34;&#34;UA-sample&#34;URL&#34;&#34;www.url.com&#34;}' WHERE "Table"."id" = '1'
```

Basically, I am doing this with:

```
 jsonString := string(MyJSimpleJsonObject)
    MyObject.MyJson = jsonString
    db.Save(&MyObject)
```

For me, the problem is `&#34` because in PGAdmin the error in pointing to that line,then, which do I have to avoid that transformation?

Comment: Use `[]byte` or `json.RawMessage` for `MyJson` field type